# Embedding VLC player in a VCL C++ Application

Tags: c++, com, vlc, vcl

I have an application exposing thousands of video files (mp4). I would like to embed a VLC media player, allowing the user to play movies, embedded on the form showing the movie items (on a flow panel).

This video show how to do it using Visual Basic and .NET https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w9jCxmazVjw

Apparently, when installing VLC, COM objects are available in order to automate the player. Is it also possible to embed it on a VCL form?

I have no experience with COM objects in C++ Builder XE3.

Comment: Is there some dependency on XE3 for you? Why not use Visual stuio, there are lots of tutorials how to us VLC or other stuff

Comment: Yes, need yo use XE3

Comment: The RADStudio IDE has a feature to import installed COM objects and generate class wrappers for them.  If the COM objects are UI embeddable, it can even generate wrapper VCL components for them.  Then you can simply drop an imported Media Player onto your Form at design-time and use it at runtime like any other UI component.